# android ListActivity Button

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an Android development problem that seems to be beyond my current skill level. The problem is as follows: I have a SQLite database and a content provider. Briefly stated, upon clicking a button, I want to see displayed on the screen some of the stored items via a `ListActivity` (or possibly a `ListView`) but I do not know how to do it.

I read the relevant stackoverflow webpages but I fail to answer my question appropriately.

To summarize:

Assume that a SQLite database has already been created.

If the SQLite database is not empty, choose some data from this SQLite database.

- Create `ListActivity` containing these chosen data.
- Create a `Button`
- Click the `Button`
- Upon clicking, the chosen items stored in the database are displayed 
  via a `ListActivity`.

I was wondering if you could help me out.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is just how to updating listview, perhaps try to look into calling notifyDataSetChanged on your listview adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data in an SQLite database or in a content provider? The two are different. If the data is in a content provider, use a loader to retrieve data, and bind the data to a ListView with a CursorAdapter. See [Loading Data in the Background](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html). Also, you want to initialize the
loader (call initLoader()) from the the button's onClick method. You can set this programmatically with an anonymous class using setOnClickListener(), or in your XML with the onClick attribute of the Button.

The advantage of a CursorLoader is that it *includes* data observation. When the data backing the Cursor changes, CursorLoader automatically calls onLoaderReset and then onCreateLoader. This is explained in more detail in the link I provided.

The API guide [List View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) explains the steps for binding a ListView to a Cursor and using a Loader.

A note: I was always confused by ListView and adapters. A ListView requires *two* layouts:

1. A layout that describes the entire screen, including the ListView view object.
2. A layout that describes the layout of each line or item in the list.

You usually bind a Cursor to a ListView with a CursorAdapter. The default implementation of CursorAdapter assumes the following:

- The Cursor contains a column named "_ID"
- Each column in the Cursor that you want to display goes to one View in the line layout.
- Data can be transferred from the Cursor to the line layout without intermediate calculations or processing.

You don't have to display all the columns in the Cursor, but each view object in the line layout can take only one column.